# Why is $ \theta(m) \propto \zeta(2) $ if it is counting lattice points in a hyperbola?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conic-sections, integer-lattices

I found this lattice point identity in a derivation of [$\zeta(2)$](https://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/cillerue/Curso/zeta2.pdf):

$$ \theta(x) = \sum_{mr \leq x} m = \sum_{r \leq x}\sum_{m=1}^{[x/r]} m =  
 \sum_{r \leq x} \left( [x/r]^2 + [x/r] \right)
=  \sum_{r \leq x} \left( [x/r]^2 +O(x/r)\right)
= \zeta(2) \cdot \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x \log x)$$

I am actually quite surprise that $\zeta(2)$ appears in this particular lattice point counting problem - since it's over a hyperbola.  Is there a geometric explanation of this fact?

Comment: Well, weighted counting. What's your geometric interpretation of $\zeta(2)$? Without one, you'll just be asking for a way to go from geometry to $\zeta(2)$, which is exactly what that calculation does.

Comment: @arctictern Yes!  Basically, I am asking for a geometric derivation of $ \frac{1}{x^2} \theta(x) \propto \zeta(2) $